# How to set own model to an interface which get generic types parameters

Tags: java, oop

This is my interface ,

```
public interface OnSendEntityMessageListener {
    public <T> void onSendEntity(Class<T> entityType, T message);
}
```

When i want to use interface like below , i get a build-in error like

> The method onSendEntity(Class, T) in the type
>   AFragment.OnSendEntityMessageListener is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Class, String)

```
private void SendASampleMessageToParent(Account account) {
      mSendEntity.onSendEntity(Account.class, "Fragment Message. : "+ account.getName());
   }
```

Modal

```
public class Account {
    String Name;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined the parameter `message` as `T` in your interface. But the `T` type argument in your example is already bound to the type `Account` when you're invoking

```
mSendEntity.onSendEntity(Account.class, "Fragment Message. : "+ account.getName());
```

You might have meant to declare your method as

```
public <T> void onSendEntity(Class<T> entityType, String message);
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your interface method to take Class, String:

```
public interface OnSendEntityMessageListener {
    public <T> void onSendEntity(Class<T> entityType, String message);
}
```